# YouTube Playlist API no longer functioning?

Tags: api, youtube

According to YouTube's docs:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_playlists

I can go to the following URL to retrieve a list of videos in a youtube playlist:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/8BCDD04DE8F771B2?v=2

Works well right? Well no... I've been unable to find a single playlist that actually works besides the one supplied by youtube. I have a playlist here: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLABD2A8CE079F70FA. It would be logical that if I simply take the ID of the playlist and plug it into the gdata URL, it should return valid data, correct? Nope... doesn't work:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLABD2A8CE079F70FA

It appears that the API doesn't work with any playlist that starts with their new "PLA" format. What do I need to do, to get the youtube API working with the new playlist system?

Comment: this is public playlist or you created with your user account

Comment: so here you are using it as public PLABD2A8CE079F70FA right?

Comment: Yes... its a public playlist.

Comment: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/playlists

Comment: use your username in the place of users

Comment: maybe your username is needed to fetch the plalists

Comment: this is not working for me as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured it out. The playlist API is designed with the OLD Youtube Playlist IDs in mind, the ones without the "PL" at the start. So if you want to retrieve information about the videos in a playlist, you need to drop the PL from the Playlist ID and then it will work fine...

Example:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/ABD2A8CE079F70FA

VS:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLABD2A8CE079F70FA

Answer (score 0):

You can add query parameters to the url. With the `max-results` query you can fetch a maximum of 50 results. If you want more than 50 requests, you need to call this multiple times with `start-index` query.

`https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLABD2A8CE079F70FA?v=2&max-results=50` will give maximum of 50 results. Fetch the next 50 results by adding the query `start-index=51&max-results=50`. Currently this is the only way you can achieve it.

Answer (score -1):

**Check this your playlist,It works fine**

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Jaxelrod/playlists/DC725B3F130398B2?v=2

Comment: because public lists are restricted nowadays

Comment: That doesn't return a list of media... it only returns the information about the playlist.

Comment: have you not received an atom feed xml,, through that only you can fetch the data

Comment: The point is to get information about the VIDEOS in the playlist... not information about the playlist itself. This is what the API is supposed to do... but its not working.