# YouTube api v2.1 cannot post video id to playlist as json object - javascript

Tags: javascript, api, post, youtube

I get a 400 error invalid JSON when I post a video id object to a youtube playlist using javascript/jquery.
The object is:

```
 { "video":
        {
         "id": "me21QEpg760"
        }
 }
```

The ajax request:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/" + plistId + '?v=2&alt=jsonc',
    data: {
          "video":
                 {
                   "id": "me21QEpg760"
                 }
          },
    dataType: 'jsonc',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'AuthSub token="' + Video.token + '"');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-GData-Key', 'key="' + Video.dev_key + '"');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('GData-Version', 2);
    },
    scope: 'https://gdata.youtube.com',
    error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(data);
    }
 });
```

I'm authenticated with oauth2 using a verified dev_key and access token. I am having no problems with GET requests - I can pull in playlist and video information just fine.

I tried changing the playlist prefix - removing "PL" from the playlist id but I still get the same results
[YouTube Playlist API no longer functioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458918/youtube-playlist-api-no-longer-functioning)

Also, tried posting to a playlist with 16 char vs. 32. No difference
[Youtube API: Adding videos to a playlist with the new 32 character playlist ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713784/youtube-api-adding-videos-to-a-playlist-with-the-new-32-character-playlist-id)

I am using api v2.1 because there is more documentation for using the api with youtube. The v3 documentation has more examples for google plus. I'd be interested in using v3 but could really use some youtube specific javascript examples to get the syntax down.

I verified that the object I'm passing in as valid JSON with JSONLint. The jsonc v2.0 guide shows this particular data object in the same format.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc

`   POST /feeds/api/users/default/favorites?alt=jsonc HTTP/1.1
    Host: gdata.youtube.com
    Content-Type: application/json
    Authorization: AuthSub token="AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN"
    GData-Version: 2
    X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY

```
{
  "data":{
     "video":{
      "id":"6aiCJubxiGI"
    }
  }
}`
```

Any ideas?